# Use Where in QueryBuilder - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a table Products(id,category_id,name);

I want to get a result like this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE category_id=$category_id OR $category_id=0;
```

When I assign $category_id with 0 value => above query will return all records.

How do I write that query in Laravel?

I've try this:

```
Products::where(function($query) use ($category_id){
         $query->where("category_id",$category_id)
        ->orWhere($category_id,0)
})->get();
```

But, Error:

It look like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `products` 
WHERE
    ( `product_category_id` = 0 OR `0` = 0 )
```

And Print Error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'`

How to fix: `'0' = 0` to `0 = 0`?

Thanks!

Comment: Please make sure to name your model `Product`, not `Products`. Models are singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [when()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
$products = Product::when($categoryId, function ($query, $categoryId) {
    $query->whereCategoryId($categoryId);
})->get();
```

This method will call the function only if the condition is truthy. You could achieve the same thing with simple `if` statement:

```
$products = Product::query();

if ($categoryId) {
    $products->whereCategoryId($categoryId);
}

$products = $products->get();
```

What you gain by using `when()` is that you don't break the chain, so you can use conditional query changes in one expression. It's useful if you want to just `return` it, for example.

Comment: It doesn't work! When pass $category_id=0. Your query return nothing! It look like: `SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE category_id IN (0,0);`

Comment: What do you expect to get if you pass `category_id = 0` though?

Comment: If I have some records with field category value are `[1,2,3,4...]`. Then when pass `$category_id=0`, It will return all records in `products` table

Comment: This changes everything. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The same before. It look like this: `SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE category_id=0`. When I pass `$category_id=0`. I want this: `SELECT * FROM Products WHERE category_id=$category_id OR $category_id=0;`. So, when I pass `$category_id=1`, the query will return all records with `category=1`, and when I pass `$category_id=0` then it return all records in `products` table.

Comment: My answer does exactly that, try again :)

Comment: I have other: `Products::where(function($query) use ($category_id){
         $query->where("category_id",$category_id)
        ->orWhereRaw("$category_id = 0");
})->get();`

Comment: Yes, this is a more dirty and less efficient way of achieving the same result. Also, make sure that you validate `$category_id` in your example, because otherwise you can end up with SQL injection. Using Query Builder without any raw methods is safe.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Robo Robok!

Answer (score 0):

**use it**

```
Products::where(function($query) use ($category_id){
         $query->where("category_id",$category_id)
        ->orWhere("category_id",0);
})->get();
```

Comment: In my data, no any record have `category_id=0`. I want when pass `$category_id=0` my query will return all records. Your way, I've used (see my post)

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong with your code is this:

```
->orWhere($category_id,0)
```

you made the column part as variable.

try this code:

```
Products::where(function($query) use ($category_id){
         return $query->where("category_id", $category_id)
        ->orWhere("category_id", 0);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = new Products;
if ($category_id != 0) {
    $product = $product->where("category_id", $category_id);
}
$products = $product->get();
```

Comment: It might be helpful to give a bit of background to your answer, that way its a little more clear for future visitors.